# What is the frame sync sync option?

Tags: lance

Interpolation and extrapolation are explained in the docs, and they make sense. What is the frame sync option? I tried looking at the code a bit, but it would help to get an official description.

Answer (score 0):

The frame-sync option instructs the client to render a given game state exactly when it was received, without attempting to smooth the objects's positions.

This mode is intended for debugging purposes only.